# Calculated Column Formula not Working

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, error, modern-experience, calculated-column-formula

I'm trying to create a calculated field with the following formula, but when I try to save the column with this formula it returns a syntax error.

What's wrong with the formula?

Formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT(Birthday,"MMMM")," ",TEXT(Birthday,"DD"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried replicating the error you are getting & your calculated column formula seems fine.

**Output**:

[image]

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Set **The data type returned from this formula is:** to **Single line of text** in column settings.

**Better version of your formula**:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Birthday]), "", CONCATENATE(TEXT([Birthday], "MMMM"), " ", TEXT([Birthday], "DD")))
```

This will return blank value when there is no value in `[Birthday]` column:

[image]